# Data field shifting through a vector of data in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I need to create a data field that will go through a vector. Data field is constant length, and it is going through the data vector shifting data field with data field length. I need the mean value of that field (A vector) that corresponds to a mean value of another field (B vector).

**Example:**

```
A=[1 5 7 8 9 10 11 13 15 18 19 25 28 30 35 40 45 48 50 51];
B=[2 4 8 9 12 15 16 18 19 20 25 27 30 35 39 40 45 48 50 55];
```

*I want to do next:*

```
A=[{1 5 7 8 9} 10 11 13 15 18 19 25 28 30 35 40 45 48 50 51];
B=[{2 4 8 9 12} 15 16 18 19 20 25 27 30 35 39 40 45 48 50 55];
```

*I want to take data from field of 5 points and get mean value. And then shift whole data field with data field length.*

```
A=[1 5 7 8 9 {10 11 13 15 18} 19 25 28 30 35 40 45 48 50 51];
B=[2 4 8 9 12 {15 16 18 19 20} 25 27 30 35 39 40 45 48 50 55];
```

*I need two vectors, C and D with mean values of this method.*

```
C=[6 13.4 27.4 45.2];
D=[7 17.6 31.2 47.6];
```

**I started something with**

```
n = length(A);

for k = 1:n

....
```

but nothing I tried worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the vector into a 5-row matrix and then compute the [`mean`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) of each column:

```
C = mean(reshape(A,5,[]),1);
D = mean(reshape(B,5,[]),1)
```